# How to read and write XML on a web service with iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, web-services

I'm working on switching an iOS app over from storing data using archiving to accessing XML files on a web service, in order to have one central database for many users.  I've found resources explaining how to use NSXMLParser, but very little that explains how to create or edit XML files on the database with information entered into text fields on the app.

The web service is up and running, but the Catch-22 is that I can't verify that my parser works properly without also being able to enter data and having it save to the web service.

The data is pretty basic.  For example, I might have a Car object that has a few NSString properties- year, make, model, color, and so on.  I need to be able to add and delete Cars, as well as edit the properties.  Suggestions?

Comment: You might consider JSON, it seems things are going that way and it is much easier to generate and parse.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but the XML web service belongs to my client so that's what I have to work with.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of reading the data, I recently wrote a simple XML parser for iOS called ConiferXML. You can check it out at [GitHub](http://www.github.com/coniferapps/coniferxml). If this doesn't work out there is also another library on [GitHub](https://github.com/nicklockwood/XMLDictionary) that is a little more complex but does the same thing.